# Чем отличается newFixedThreadPool от newSingleThreadExecutor

Tags: java

Разбираю конкурентность и заметил такие вариации Executor-а
Для однопоточности

```
   Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
```

И можно сделать так

```
 Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
```

По сути это аналоги ? или у них есть отличие ?Не бера в счет то что `fixedPool` настраеваемый . я про конкретно данный случай

Answer (score 2):

Согласно описанию [newSingleThreadExecutor()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor()) использует только один поток, что равнозначно: [newFixedThreadPool(1)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)). Но есть отличие от эквивалентного `newFixedThreadPool(1)`, в том, что возвращенный исполнитель гарантированно не может быть перенастроен для использования дополнительных потоков.

А `newFixedThreadPool(...)` создает пул потоков с фиксированным количеством потоков.

---

Посмотрите описание этих методов:

[public static ExecutorService newSingleThreadExecutor()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor())

> Creates an Executor that uses a single worker thread operating off an
> unbounded queue. (Note however that if this single thread terminates
> due to a failure during execution prior to shutdown, a new one will
> take its place if needed to execute subsequent tasks.) Tasks are
> guaranteed to execute sequentially, and no more than one task will be
> active at any given time. Unlike the otherwise equivalent
> newFixedThreadPool(1) the returned executor is guaranteed not to be
> reconfigurable to use additional threads.

[public static ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int))

> Creates a thread pool that reuses a fixed number of threads operating
> off a shared unbounded queue. At any point, at most nThreads threads
> will be active processing tasks. If additional tasks are submitted
> when all threads are active, they will wait in the queue until a
> thread is available. If any thread terminates due to a failure during
> execution prior to shutdown, a new one will take its place if needed
> to execute subsequent tasks. The threads in the pool will exist until
> it is explicitly shutdown.